# C# Iterating through dictionary of type <enum, struct> is returning null without error

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, foreach, null

A previously working Dictionary foreach loop is now suddenly broken (shown below). The dictionary stores data in the form of a struct, and is sorted/indexed based on a custom enum.

Previously it was working fine. Upon inspection/breakpoints, the data does exist/IS there, however Unity/C#/Something doesn't seem to be able to see the data suddenly.

There is no modification to that data in the foreach loop, the purpose is to simply determine if a List parameter in each struct is empty or not and set a boolean.

I'm at a total loss as to why this is happening, or what could cause it, so any suggestions is appreciated.

**Original Class**

```
TargetController.UpdateSensesListData();

foreach(KeyValuePair<Controller.TypeEnum, Controller.DataStruct> list in TargetController.SensesList)
{
    if(list.Value.objects.Count > 0)
    {
        booleanVar = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class DataStruct
{
    public int priority;
    public Senses thisSense;
    public List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
}

public void Start()
{
    //SensesPriorityList is set in the Unity Inspector. Its simply a list
    //  of the TypeEnums that are used as keys for the dictionary.
    if(SensesPriorityList.count > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SensesPriorityList.Count; i++)
        {
            DataStruct data = new DataStruct
            {
                priority = i,
                sense = Getsense(SensesPriorityList[i]),
                objects = new List<GameObject>()
            };

            SensesList.Add(SensesPriorityList[i], data);
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateSensesListData()
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<TypeEnum, DataStruct> sense in SensesList)
    {
        if(sense.Value.sense != null)
            sense.Value.Objects = sense.Value.sense.UpdateSense();

        if(sense.Value.objects.Count > 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

In the above example, "DictionaryVariable" DOES have data (is not null), and the second item in the dictionary has data (the count > 0) so it should for all intents and purposes be setting the bool to true. but its not. When I looked, list reads as "Null" (but upon closer inspection, the dictionary is not null, but rather the OtherClass.Struct data is null - when it is not)

Comment: Check if `list.Value` is null then check if `list.Value.ListVariable` is null. One of those should be null...

Comment: Can you show real code? Details are, you know, sometimes important.

Comment: @sinatr I've updated it with actual variables. Didn't bother with the data types because its irrelevant. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Programmer I modified it slightly recently so that the foreach is now done in the other class and it works fine. But iirc, I believe list.Value was reading as Null in the original class. but in the Class where the data resides (TargetController.SensesList) it was not null.  -- It does work now, but I'm just curious as to why it stopped working in the first place in case it happens again, and I'm not able to fix it in the same manner.

Comment: @Programmer I just undid the changes and it is list.Value that is null. However if I hover my cursor over TargetController.SensesList, Value is not null.

Comment: Forget about the cursor stuff you mentioned. Just use `Debug.Log` to check if it is null. Note that if you keep changing your code while someone is helping you, you will be making it harder to get help... Yo ujust changed the 
 `ListVariable` variable....... Please post what your `Controller` and `DataStruct` variable look like. Also show how you are adding stuff to the dictionary.

Comment: @Programmer I've updated the code with stuff from the other classes. Whilst I was updating the OP, I noticed that the DataStruct isn't actually a struct at all. its a class that is nested within the Controller Class. I'm not sure if this would affect anything in any way - but as I said it previously was working fine. As for adding stuff to the dictionary, that is only done on Awake/Start as shown above (in a moment - as of writing this. I forgot to include that part)

Comment: Ok, still don't know what's wrong. Double click on that error from the Editor and it will show you which line of code is the problem.Please tell me what that code is. If possible, post the `TypeEnum` too

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no error :(

Comment: Regarding the Debug.Logs, that data is correct, the count is accurate, and the List.Value is not null either. But in the code, it seems to read it as null, (or count == 0) and never sets the boolean correctly :/